# Setting number in list that's less than 1% to 1% while keeping total 100%

Tags: c#, logic, width, percentage

I'm running into a logic issue with my web application.

Background: There will be a bunch of div's in a row across the page. Their CSS `width:` percentage is equal to the percentage the item's `int` value divided by the list's total `int` value.

The problem: I don't want any of the widths to be less than 1%.  This means I have to increase the width of items lower than 1% to 1%, and reduce the widths of all of the other items so the percentage total adds back up to 100% exactly.

This creates an issue where an item that was already exactly 1% gets reduced to less than 1%.

I've tried so many ways to do this, but this is my current iteration.  I made it simple for myself and you guys by putting it into a console application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PercentageOfTotal
{
    public class Item
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public double Percent { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var items = new List<Item>();

            items.Add(new Item { Value = 26 });
            items.Add(new Item { Value = 31 });
            items.Add(new Item { Value = 47 });
            items.Add(new Item { Value = 175 });
            items.Add(new Item { Value = 50 });
            items.Add(new Item { Value = 1 });
            items.Add(new Item { Value = 74 });
            items.Add(new Item { Value = 8 });
            items.Add(new Item { Value = 219 });
            items.Add(new Item { Value = 169 });

            int sum = items.Sum(x => x.Value);
            double minPercentage = 0.01;

            System.Console.WriteLine("Value - Percent");

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                item.Percent = item.Value / (double)sum;
                System.Console.WriteLine(item.Value + " - " + item.Percent);
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine("---------");
            System.Console.WriteLine(items.Sum(x => x.Value) + " - " + items.Sum(x => x.Percent));
            System.Console.WriteLine("\n");

            var itemsLessThanOnePercent = items.Where(x => x.Percent < minPercentage).ToList();
            var itemsGreaterThanOrEqualToOnePercent = items.Where(x => x.Percent >= minPercentage).ToList();
            double totalPercentageLessThanOne = itemsLessThanOnePercent.Sum(x => x.Percent);
            double reduceEachGreaterThanOneBy = ((itemsLessThanOnePercent.Count() * minPercentage) - totalPercentageLessThanOne) / itemsGreaterThanOrEqualToOnePercent.Count();

            foreach (var item in itemsGreaterThanOrEqualToOnePercent)
            {
                item.Percent = item.Percent - reduceEachGreaterThanOneBy;
            }

            foreach (var item in itemsLessThanOnePercent)
            {
                item.Percent = minPercentage;
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine("Value - Percent");

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(item.Value + " - " + item.Percent);
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine("---------");
            System.Console.WriteLine(items.Sum(x => x.Value) + " - " + items.Sum(x => x.Percent));
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this case it reduces the `item` with `Value = 8` to less than 1% (0.009) because the `item.Value` was already 1% in the first place.

Basically, I want the `item`'s percentage to be relative to the overall sum of `item.Value` without having any percentages less than 1% and the total of percentages equaling 100%.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate items in order of increasing `Value`. For each item, assign percentage and if less that minimum - carry over that overflow to distribute to the rest of items. Well it's hard to explain in words I admit, so here is sample code:

```
double overflow = 0;
int left = items.Count;
// loop in order of ascending value
foreach (var item in items.OrderBy(c => c.Value))
{
    // calculate part of overflow to assign to this item, based on total and how much items still left
    var overflowForItem = overflow / left;
    // assign a bit less than expected if there is overflow
    item.Percent = (item.Value - overflowForItem) / (double)sum;
    // reduce overflow (we just assigned part of it above)
    overflow -= overflowForItem;
    if (item.Percent < minPercentage) {                    
        overflow += (minPercentage - item.Percent) * sum;
        item.Percent = minPercentage;
    }                
    left--;                
}
```

Comment: I admit, the question was also hard to explain in words.  None the less, that's amazing!  Thank you!  Extremely clever solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the items as iteration until expected percentages performed. And you can do it recursively. I modified your code like this;

```
    static void Main()
    {

        var items = new List<Item>();

        items.Add(new Item { Value = 26 });
        items.Add(new Item { Value = 31 });
        items.Add(new Item { Value = 47 });
        items.Add(new Item { Value = 175 });
        items.Add(new Item { Value = 50 });
        items.Add(new Item { Value = 1 });
        items.Add(new Item { Value = 74 });
        items.Add(new Item { Value = 8 });
        items.Add(new Item { Value = 219 });
        items.Add(new Item { Value = 169 });

        int sum = items.Sum(x => x.Value);
        double minPercentage = 0.01;

        System.Console.WriteLine("Value - Percent");

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item.Percent = item.Value / (double)sum;
            System.Console.WriteLine(item.Value + " - " + item.Percent);
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("---------");
        System.Console.WriteLine(items.Sum(x => x.Value) + " - " + items.Sum(x => x.Percent));
        System.Console.WriteLine("\n");
        CalculatePercents(items,minPercentage);

        System.Console.WriteLine("Value - Percent");

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(item.Value + " - " + item.Percent);
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("---------");
        System.Console.WriteLine(items.Sum(x => x.Value) + " - " + items.Sum(x => x.Percent));
        System.Console.ReadLine();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void CalculatePercents(List<Item> items,double minPercentage)
    {

        var itemsLessThanOnePercent = items.Where(x => x.Percent < minPercentage).ToList();
        var itemsGreaterThanOrEqualToOnePercent = items.Where(x => x.Percent >= minPercentage).ToList();
        double totalPercentageLessThanOne = itemsLessThanOnePercent.Sum(x => x.Percent);
        double reduceEachGreaterThanOneBy = ((itemsLessThanOnePercent.Count() * minPercentage) - totalPercentageLessThanOne) / itemsGreaterThanOrEqualToOnePercent.Count();

        foreach (var item in itemsGreaterThanOrEqualToOnePercent)
        {
            item.Percent = item.Percent - reduceEachGreaterThanOneBy;
        }

        foreach (var item in itemsLessThanOnePercent)
        {
            item.Percent = minPercentage;
        }
        var minPercentagesItems = items.Where(x => x.Percent < minPercentage).ToList();
        if (minPercentagesItems.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        CalculatePercents(minPercentagesItems,minPercentage);
    }
```

Comment: In this case, the values add up to 100.1% if I were to convert the double to a CSS percentage string.  That would overflow one item to the next line. I did consider this, but I actually thought it would run infinitely as the .01's and less than .01's fought until the end while getting reduced and increased!